# How to Change Title Attribute in React Native Button Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button

I have a few React components that look something like this within an app:

```
 <View style={{margin: 5}}>
        <Button title='Enable Headlights' color='#00759A' onClick={doChanges}/>
 </View>
```

I want the Button component to change its color and text whenever its clicked. I was planning on having the function doChanges do this, but I can't figure out a way to modify the title and color attributes. I've seen custom made components that make these kinds of changes in state by calling setState within the component, but Button isn't a component that I made. I tried doing something along the lines of:

```
 var text = "Enable headlights"
 function doChanges(text) {
       text = "Disable headlights"
 }
  
 <View style={{margin: 5}}>
        <Button title={text} color='#00759A' onClick={()=> {doChanges(text)}}/>
 </View>
```

But that doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. I think it's because even though the variable text is changing, the actual component isn't rerendering, so the changes in text never actually appear.

There doesn't seem to be a way to force the component to rerender, and I don't see how there's a way I can modify the title and color attributes of the Button component.

Do I have to make a custom component that's subclassed from Button in order to get the functionality I want? Or is there a specific way for how I'm supposed to go about doing something like this in React?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `useState` hook to update some prop and re-render component with new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are supposed to make changes at the UI level then you should use the state to render the updated view.

like:

If you are **using Class Component**:

```
class Demo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            buttonText: "Enable headlights"
        }
        this.doChanges = this.doChanges.bind(this);
    }

     function doChanges(text) {
         this.setState({ buttonText: "Disable headlights" });
     }

     render() {
         return (
              <View style={{margin: 5}}>
                  <Button title={this.state.} color='#00759A' onClick={()=> {doChanges(text)}}/>
              </View>
         )
     }
}
```

If you are **using Functional Component**:

```
const Demo = props => {
    
     const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Enable headlights")

     function doChanges(text) {
         setButtonText("Disable headlights");
     }

     return (
          <View style={{margin: 5}}>
              <Button title={text} color='#00759A' onClick={()=> {doChanges(text)}}/>
          </View>
     )
}
```

check out more about the state:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html